# Python BeautifulSoup and multithreading performance

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing some web pages using BeautifulSoup4 and Multithreading. Each thread is taking jobs (URLs) from a queue and calls `parse_results_page` which makes a HTTP request (calling `get_html_page_source()`) then parse each item on the page in a for loop.

What I've noticed:
If I have 5 threads, it takes from 0.7 - 8 seconds* to parse a page.
If I have 50 threads, it takes from 25 - 60 seconds* to parse a page.
Even with 10 threads the running time increases pretty much.

*the execution is measured after the HTTP request was made so the differences are not because of my bandwidth or server's response time.

Also having 50 threads increases the memory usage up to 6GB.

Can somebody explain why is this happening and how I can optimize my code for more threads?

Below is my code.
Thanks

```
    def parse_item(self, item, *args):
    """Parse a given item
    @item - beautifulsoup.Tag object
    @queue - queue of dicts
    """
    item_url = item.find('h2', class_="heading")
    item_url = re.sub(r'\.html?.+$', '.html', item_url.a['href'])
    if 'redirect' in item_url or '/external/url' in item_url:
        return

    item_title = item.find('span', class_="mp-listing-title")
    item_title = item_title.get_text().strip() if item_title else None

    description = item.find('div', class_="listing-title-description")
    if description:
        description.h2.extract()
        description = description.get_text().strip()
        description = ' '.join(description.split())

    price = item.find('span', class_="price")
    if price:
        try:
            raw_price = price.get_text().strip().replace(
                                            '.', '').replace(',', '.')
            currency, price = raw_price.split()
            price = price
            try:
                currency = self.currency_code[currency.strip()]
            except KeyError:
                currency = None
                price = raw_price
        except ValueError:
            price = raw_price
            currency = None
    else:
        price, currency = None, None

    seller_id = item.find('div', class_="seller-name")
    if seller_id:
        seller_id = seller_id.find('a')
    if seller_id:
        seller_id = seller_id['href'].split('/')[-1].replace('.html',
                                                             '')
    location = item.find('div', class_='location-name')
    if location:
        location = location.get_text().split(',')
        if len(location) == 1:
            city = location[0]
            region = None
        else:
            city = location[0]
            region = location[1].strip()
    else:
        city, region = None, None
    date_posted = ''
    date_string = item.find('div', class_="date"
                            ).get_text().strip()
    if 'Vandaag' in date_string:
        date_posted = datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime(
                                                        '%Y-%m-%d')

    elif 'Gisteren' in date_string:
        date_posted = datetime.datetime.now(
                                    ).date() - datetime.timedelta(1)
        date_posted = date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    elif 'Eergisteren' in date_string:
        date_posted = datetime.datetime.now(
                                    ).date() - datetime.timedelta(2)
        date_posted = date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    else:
        date_posted = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string.replace(
                                                            '.', ''),
                                                 "%d %b '%y")

        date_posted = date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_scraped = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
                                                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return {"Url": item_url,
            'Category': args[0],
            "AdTitle": item_title,
            "Subcategory": args[1],
            "Description": description,
            "Currency": currency,
            "Price": price,
            "SellerId": seller_id,
            "SellerPhone": None,
            "SellerWebsite": None,
            "SellerEmail": None,
            "SellerCity": city,
            "SellerCountry": None,
            "SellerRegion": region,
            "DatePosted": date_posted,
            "DateSaved": date_scraped}

def parse_results_page(self, url, queue):
    """Get all items from a given page
    @url - string
    @queue - output queue
    """

    page = self.get_html_page_source(url)
    if not page:
        return
    page = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
    items = page.find_all('article')
    breadcrumb = page.find('ul', class_="breadcrumbs").find_all('span')
    category = breadcrumb[0].get_text().strip()
    subcategory = breadcrumb[1].get_text().strip()
    for item in items:
        queue.put(self.parse_item(item, category, subcategory))
```